# Is there a way to create a word document or pdf in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I would like to create a word document or a pdf of the NSLog output that I have running right now.  Is there a way to do that simply or at all?  I have googled the crap out of the issue and have been unable to find a result short of going into xcode and then organizer to find the output.  I would prefer to not have to do that.

example:

NSLog(@"X: %.3f Y: %.3f", accelerometer.x, accelerometer.y); 
//move this output straight into a word document or something of that nature that can then be pulled from the device later.

Thanks

Comment: try this https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger

Comment: I would write your log to text file and save in the application document folder first.  Once your have done that, then I would try to convert it to PDF or some other format.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your NSLogs to a file using a method like this:

```
- (void)redirectNSLogToDocuments 
{
     NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *pathForLog = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];

     freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

Then you can convert that file to whatever format you want.

Comment: Can I pull that document off of the iOS system after the fact?  I am unclear about the file extraction properties within iOS as well?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack

There's a built in file logger that outputs to txt files.

It also offers a lot more control over NSLog and you can easily stop logging without having to comment all the calls out

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using CocoaLumberJack which will put it into a .txt document.  Now to figure out a way to programmatically move the text file to my hd in linux. :(